# Excel IF Function with LEFT Function criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am using GOOGLE SHEETS and I am trying to manipulate received data in the following way:

[image]

In column A, I have a number. In column B I have a department. In column C I change the number to concatenate with the first letter of column B's value ONLY IF the number starts with 36. If it doesn't it simply returns the new number as the original number.  I had to use the SEARCH function because IF LEFT
is not working here, so the issue is if changes the number wherever it finds a 36, instead of just those numbers starting with 36.  Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

This formula is used in column C :

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("36",A2),CONCATENATE(A2,LEFT(B2,1)),A2),A2)
```

Here is the IF LEFT function that I've tried :

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A2,2) = "36",CONCATENATE(A2,LEFT(B2,1)),A2),A2)
```

(If errors occur or the old number doesn't start with 36 the new number should remain the original)

Thanks in advance

Edit:  Changed LEFT function to correct ranges, forgot to edit this in initially when asking the question.

Comment: What happens when you use the LEFT function?

Comment: Please pick either Excel or GS. They are not the same unfortunately. Looks like you are working in GS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,2)="36",A2 & LEFT(B2,1),A2)
```

[image]

This approach does not use `IFERROR()` or `CONCATENATE()`.
It assumes your version of Excel uses the English version of the function names and uses **,** as the argument separator.

Comment: Thank you very much!  this works perfectly. I see one of the reasons for my struggle was because of blank spaces created when I used a split function to retrieve column A's data from another range.

Comment: @JacquesNaudé If you have issues with spaces at the start and the end of the data, you can use `TRIM` to get rid of them (e.g. `TRIM("   some text ")` will give `"some text"`, with the spaces removed from the start and end)

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,2)="36",CONCATENATE(A2,LEFT(B2,1)),A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=A2 & LEFT(B2, LEFT(A2, 2)="36")
```

This is a ['golfed' answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com): made as short as possible (although, I have left the spaces in for readability)

If the first 2 characters of cell A2 are `"36"`, then `LEFT(A2, 2)="36"` will be `True`.  Otherwise, `LEFT(A2, 2)="36"` will be `False`.

Excel will treat `True` and `False` as `1` and `0` - so, the `LEFT(B2, LEFT(A2, 2)="36")` will take either the *first* character from cell B2, or *no* characters from cell B2, and add that to the end of the value from cell A2.